# Symfony2 ContextErrorException

Tags: symfony

I have in my entity a method:

```
public function getProviderAvailabilities($providerKey)
```

When i try add a form field by `$builder->add('ProviderAvailabilities')` I get the following error

> ContextErrorException: Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   getProviderAvailabilities() called in
>   Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php on line 211 and
>   defined in

How can I fix it? PS. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Show us your entity. Do you have a property with that name ? Your CamelCase seems a bit off ...

Comment: is it souldn't be `$builder->add('providerAvailabilities')` ?

Comment: `providerAvailabilities` is the entity property? What type of property is it? Is the FormType mapped to the entity as it's `data_class`?

Comment: Property looks like: `private $providerAvailabilities = array();` When I try add form filed like this `$builder->add('providerAvailabilities')` I get the error I write above. get methody for this property in entity is `public function getProviderAvailabilities($providerKey)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an argument in your getter method. Maybe you can change your method definition like this:

```
public function getProviderAvailabilities($providerKey = null)
```

You should provide us with some more code of your getter method.